# Solving Heat Equation using Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, characteristics

Given the equation,
$$u_{xx}=\frac{1}{\kappa}u_t$$

How would I go about solving using Method of Characteristics? I know I end up with the PDE being transformed into something along the lines of
$$u_{\phi\phi}+first~order~terms+other~terms=0$$
However, when trying to obtain $\phi$ and $\zeta$, I run into a few problems as I get to
$$\frac{dt}{d x}=0$$
then have to solve
$$\int dt=\int 0 \cdot dx$$

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your actual question 'How do I solve $\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} x} = 0$?'

Comment: The method of characteristics is for hyperbolic PDEs but yours is parabolic. Also the PDE you show is already in the form you want (if you subtract the rhs).

Comment: I've solved parabolic pde's in the past ie $u_{xx}-u_{yy}=0$. So to find one of the characteristics I solve for $u_{xx}=0$?

Comment: $u_{xx}-u_{yy}=0$ is hyperbolic.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why method of characteristics doesn't work for the heat equation?

Comment: @HattieS in fact it's false. The Fokker-Planck equation (which is similar to the heat equation, and parabolic) can of course be solved using characteristics, for instance choosing a harmonic potential. However, the trick in that case is to step first to Fourier space to find nontrivial characteristics.